# Can't generate grub.cfg

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Software Up To Date installed a new kernel for me yesterday ( Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.13.0-48-generic) After rebooting I ran grub customizer and got an error. Same from update-grub:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-54-generic
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found CentOS release 6.6 (Final) on /dev/sdb1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-54-generic
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found CentOS release 6.6 (Final) on /dev/sdb1
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: line no: 146
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
```

Line 146 of /boot/grub/grub.cfg is:

```
menuentry "CentOS release 6.6 (Final) (on /dev/sdb1)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3bc75d12-4328-4e95-9274-8a825181d0d2 <<-Line 146
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/sdb1
    initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64.img
}
```

Line 146 of /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new is:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 105996f5-ba7e-46f4-b0de-eb5299a19563
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic root=UUID=105996f5-ba7e-46f4-b0de-eb5299a19563 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
}
function gfxmode {  <<- Line 146
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
            set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
            set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
```

It prompts me to "check for errors" in /etc/grub.d/* but how would I know what's an error there?  Since I've never touched those files, I don't know what they should contain.

Comment: You can post the content to http://pastebin.com, and people will check it.

Comment: I notice that the kernel referenced in that line is the old one.